# How can I increase the width of the primeng table pagination (page turning) buttons?

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I have a large primeng table:

```
<p-table #dt [value]="artefacts" [columns]="cols" [paginator]="true" [rows]="numberRows" [tableStyle]="{'table-layout':'auto'}">
```

The large number of entries results in the table having more than 100 pages. However, the width of the pagination buttons is fixed and only the font size decreases for two digit numbers. For three digit numbers it looks like this:

[image: pagination 3 digit bug]

Is it possible to overwrite some css property to increase the width of those buttons?

Comment: Are you able to create a stackblitz that reproduces the problem please?

Comment: you can try ```.ui-paginator .ui-paginator-pages .ui-paginator-page{
  min-width: 2.5em !important;
}``` in your styles.css

Comment: I can not reproduce it actually. In the stackblitz I created https://stackblitz.com/edit/test-p-table-hfvjz9 the paginatior button scaling works like a charm. However, @fatemefazli your fix works for me! You might want to add it as an answer. I will try to figure out why it does not work for me.

Comment: Do you add the styles to your styles.css of src folder?

Comment: @fatemefazli I have no styles.css (jhipster generated project) thus I put it in the global.css of src/main/webapp/content/css/ folder

Comment: so does it work? in global.css ?

Comment: Yes, it works with your css settings in global.css!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
.ui-paginator .ui-paginator-pages .ui-paginator-page{ 
min-width: 2.5em !important; 
}
```

Note that to add the styles in your `styles.css` of src folder.